# Can I see all questions about my favorite topic daily?

Tags: support, tag-watching, subscription

I am new to Stack Overflow.  I want to pick some tags as my favorites, and I want see each question that has one or more of my favorite tags on a daily basis.

For example, could they be sent to my email? Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, through a subscription to a tag or tag(s).

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/improved-tag-sets/

and

https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular